# How can I copy formatted text using HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to implement a button on my webpage that allows users to copy formatted text to their clipboard. Shortcuts and context menus are disabled on my page, but I still want users to be able to copy formatted text, similar to using Ctrl + C. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

p.s. The execCommand() method is deprecated. so this will not be an answer.
p.s. i am looking for a method that does not use any external libraries.

i am a total beginner in js so any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginner too, but I think this was the problem I've encountered.
Though I'm not sure what the formatted text format is, if it's plain text, you may use `navigator.clipboard.writeText()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText

```js
button.addEventListener("click", writeClipboardText("<empty clipboard>"));

async function writeClipboardText() {
  try {
    const text = document.getElementById('textToCopy').innerText;
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.